# Integral Representation of the solution to the advection-diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I am working on a problem in my PDE homework and I am stuck on one portion of the problem. I am given the following PDE IVP:
$$u_t+au_x=u+\kappa u_{xx}, \ -\infty<x<\infty, \ t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=\phi(x), \ -\infty<x<\infty $$
where $a$ and $\kappa$ are constants.

What I want to do is transform my equation in a way that will change it into the normal heat equation:
$$u_t=\kappa u_{xx},$$

once I have that I know what to do.

My homework has the hint that I should transform the independent variable $(x,t)\rightarrow (x-at,t)$ and replace $u$ by $v=e^{-t}u$ as the dependent variable.

I have tried that and what I get is: $-e^{-t}u+e^{-t}u_t=e^{-t}u+\kappa e^{-t}u_{xx}.$

Which I believe is just $v_t$ on the left, but not $\kappa v_{xx}$ on the right.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done the variables transformation, which we must do first. Given a solution $u$, let $w$ satisfy $w(x-at,t)=u(x,t)$. Then $w_x(x-at,t)=u_x(x,t)$, $w_{xx}(x-at,t)=u_{xx}(x,t)$ and
$$u_t(x,t)=-aw_x(x-at,t)+w_t(x-at,t)=-au_x(x,t)+w_t(x-at,t)$$
This implies
$$w_t(x-at,t)=u_t(x,t)+au_x(x,t)=u(x,t)+\kappa u_{xx}(x,t)=w(x-at,t)+\kappa w_{xx}(x-at,t)$$
so since $(x,t)\mapsto(x-at,t)$ is a bijection, $w$ satisfies $w_t=w+\kappa w_{xx}$. Now put $v(x,t)=e^{-t}w(x,t)$. It follows quickly that $v_t=\kappa v_{xx}$. Once you have solved this equation you simply have to back substitute to find $u$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $u(x, t) := e^{t} v(x - a t, t)$. Then 
\begin{align}
u_t(x, t) & = u - a e^t v_x(x - a t, t) + e^t v_t(x - a t, t)
\\
u_x(x, t) & = e^t v_x(x - a t, t)
\\
u_{xx}(x, t) & = e^t v_{xx}(x - a t, t)
.
\end{align}

Plug this into the original equation and simplify to obtain an equation for $v$.

Comment: That would work, but the hint says we need to use $e^{-t}$. Which I believe is important because later in the proof we need certain parts to be bounded, and $e^t$ would become quite large as $t\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: In particular we need boundedness as $t\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: well, your hint says $v = e^{-t} u$ which is the same as $e^t v = u$